# Calendar2(calendar2は元コードに見当たらないですが...)

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Many years calendar
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("年は?: ");
        String str1 = in.readLine();
        System.out.print("月は?: ");
        String str2 = in.readLine();

        int year = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(str2);
        int dow = dayofweek(year, month);
        int dim = daysinmonth(year, month);

        showcal(dow, dim);
    }

    // カレンダーを表示する
    public static void showcal(int dow, int days) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("日 月 火 水 木 金 土");

        int d = 1;
        int i;

        // 最初の週の表示 
        for(i = 0; i < dow; i++){
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        for(; i < 7; i++){
            System.out.print(" " + d + " ");
            d++;
        }
        System.out.println();

        // 二週目以降の表示
        for(int j = 0; d <= days; j++){
            for(i = 0; i < 7 && d <= days; i++){
                if(d < 10)
                    System.out.print(" " + d + " ");
                else
                    System.out.print(d + " ");
                d++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // 月の日数をかえす
    public static int daysinmonth(int year, int month) throws Exception{
        int dim = 31;
        if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
            dim = 30;
        if(month == 2){
            if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
                dim = 29; // うるう年
            else
                dim = 28;
        }
        return dim;
    }

    // 年の日数をかえす
    public static int daysinyear(int year) throws Exception{
        int diy;
        if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
            diy = 366; // うるう年
        else
            diy = 365;
        return diy;
    }

    // 月の初日の曜日をかえす
    public static int dayofweek(int year, int month) throws Exception{
        int days = 0;
        int y = 0, m = 0;
        int dow = 0;

        // 2000年以降
        if(year >= 2000){
            for(y = 2000; y < year; y++){
                days = days + daysinyear(y);
            }
            for(m = 1; m < month; m++){
                days = days + daysinmonth(year, m);
            }
            dow = (days + 6) % 7;
        }

        // 1999年以前
        else{
            for(m = month; m <= 12; m++){
                days = days + daysinmonth(year, m);
            }
            for(y = year + 1; y < 2000; y++){
                days = days + daysinyear(y);
            }
            dow = 6 - days % 7;
        }
        return dow;
    }
}
```

上のjavaのやつをcalendar obj = new calendar2();もいれて、コンパイルして、calendar2.classとMany years calendar.classを出したいのです。

どうやったらいいか分かりますか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずクラス名の部分を`class Many years calendar`から`class Many_years_calendar`に変えたらコンパイルはできて`Many_years_calendar.class`ができると思います。スペースはデリミタとして働くのでこのようには書けないです。

Comment: 一般的なJavaでの[クラスの命名規則](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)に従って、`public class ManyYearsCalendar`や、`Calendar2`(`calendar2`は元コードに見当たらないですが...)にした方が、おそらく回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

まずこのクラスを Many years calendarから Many_years_calendar に変えます。
ファイル名とクラス名は一致させる必要があるため、Many_years_calendar.javaの名前に変更してください。

また、

> calendar obj = new calendar2();もいれて、コンパイルして、calendar2.classとMany years calendar.classを出したい

とありますが、Many_years_calendarクラスからcalendar2クラスを利用している箇所はありません。これは何故コンパイルする必要があると思われたのでしょうか。